# Vue router - optional route groups

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a question about vue-router. How could I accomplish a route / routes like this:

```
example.com/blog/category/value/tags/value/page/value
```

Category, tags and page should be optional.

So if I visit 
`example.com/blog/category/value/page/value` - it should load the same component.

I'm using vue 2.

Thanks!

Comment: you are looking for dynamic matching check this [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

Comment: yes, I checked the docs, I also checked the examples on github, but they don't really answer my question. Could you give me an example or point me in to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
const Blog = {
  template: `<div>Blog 
    <h3>{{  $route.params.category }}  {{  $route.params.page }}</h3>
  </div>`
};

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/blog(/category/)?:category([^\/]+)?(/page/)?:page?', component: Blog }
  ]
});

const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app');
```

html:

```
<div id="app">
    <p>
       <router-link to="/blog">blog</router-link>
       <router-link to="/blog/category/cat1/page/page1">/blog/link1</router-link>
       <router-link to="/blog/category/cat2/page/page2">/blog/link2</router-link>
    </p>
      <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

[Vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-matching/app.js)

Comment: Hmm, seems to be working for the most part. The only issues I see with this is that when you go to a route for example:
 
example.com/blog/category/test 

the :category value gets split, only getting the first character of the value for example test will be 't', and the rest is assigned to a :page value, which will be 'est'. But if you would go example.com/blog/page/test than it works fine.

Comment: @PauliusKrutkis try my new answer

Comment: Yes, now it works as expected, thanks! There is one more problem I have, but I guess it's beyond the scope of this question. It's difficult referencing this route in the code. Right now this: <router-link to="/blog/category/cat1/page/page1">/blog/link1</router-link> will work just fine, but I need to do more complicated logic behind this structure, I was hoping I could reference this route by name like this <router-link :to="{ name: 'blog', params: { category_value: 'test', page_value: 2 }}">link</router-link> but what happens is that the result becomes this: /blogtest2 :/ , but thanks anyway!

Comment: @PauliusKrutkis did you eventually find a solution for the last problem about linking to named routes?

Comment: I did not, maybe this was a bad solution for the thing I wanted to build, I've instead built my own custom router for this. On the other hand if I used query string structure than this would have worked, but I think that 'pretty' URL structure would be better for SEO.